# How can I create a window that can't be closed?

Tags: window, deletion

I create a window with the following

```
  (setq ook-window (display-buffer-in-side-window buffer '((side . bottom))))
  (set-window-dedicated-p ook-window t)
```

But then when I go to the main window and press C-X 1, it closes my ook-window. What can I do to prevent this from happening so the window will only close when I choose?

From the documentation I would have thought setting it as dedicated should have done the trick, but it seems I am still missing something. I can see neo-tree does something similar, it only closes when I run neotree-toggle.

EDIT, to clarify

> I want to bind a key (f9), so when I press f9 it will make the window appear and then the only way to make it dissappear is by pressing f9 again.

Comment: As far as I understand it means that the buffer is dedicated to the window, not that the window is not closable.

Comment: Perhaps what you want is more this [Side-Windows](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Side-Windows.html) ?

Comment: @rpluim I am creating the window as a side window, but this doesn't seem to be all that is necessary.

Comment: Please specify just what you mean by *"so the window will only close when I choose"*. It's not clear what actions by you constitute choosing and what actions do not.

Comment: I want to bind a key *(f9)*, so when I press f9 it will make the window appear and then the only way to make it dissappear is by pressing f9 again.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I have figured it out. I need to add this line :

```
(set-window-parameter ook-window 'no-delete-other-windows t)
```

As referenced in this [issue](https://github.com/jaypei/emacs-neotree/issues/296).